# Can a `default` case also be in the middle or on the beginning of a switch?

Tags: c#

I have some switch-case blocks. Which do have a default case.

The `default` is normally placed at the "end" of the switch section. Like in ths example

```cs
switch(n)
{
    case 1: 
        // code for case 1 here...
        break;
    case 3: 
        // code for case 3 here...
        break;
    case 2:
    default: 
        // code here is for default and case 2
        break;
}
```

I know that the `case 2` could be ommit, but we in the team decided to keep all possible cases in the switch.

On the other-side I would love to have the order of 1, 2 and 3.

So my question would be, can I move the default in the `middle` of the switch? I found on [msdn - the-switch-statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-switch-statement) that the default can be placed everywhere.

> The default case can appear in any place within a switch statement. Regardless of its position, the default case is always evaluated last and only if all other case patterns aren't matched, except if goto default is encountered.

```cs
switch(n)
{
    case 1: 
        // code for case 1 here...
        break;
    case 2:
    default: 
        // code here is for default and case 2
        break;
    case 3: 
        // code for case 3 here...
        break;
}
```

Or would it be possible even possible to change the order or `case 2` and default?

```cs
switch(n)
{
    case 1: 
        // code for case 1 here...
        break;
    default: 
    case 2:
        // code here is for default and case 2
        break;
    case 3: 
        // code for case 3 here...
        break;
}
```

The last code snippet, keeps the "order" and also shows that "2" is same as default. I like that most for readability.

My question, is the placement of "default" in the middle of the switch block save? Or was that introduced in later c# version?

From the comments ... I added my test-method

```cs
        [TestMethod]
        public void SwitchMethodWithDefaultsInMiddle()
        {
            Func<int, string> func = (n) => {
                string ret = "";
                switch (n)
                {
                    case 1:
                        // code for case 1 here...
                        ret = "case 1";
                        break;
                    default:
                    case 2:
                        // code here is for default and case 2
                        ret = "case 2 or default";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        // code for case 3 here...
                        ret = "case 3";
                        break;
                }
                return ret;
            };

            Assert.AreEqual("case 1", func(1));
            Assert.AreEqual("case 2 or default", func(2));
            Assert.AreEqual("case 3", func(3));

            Assert.AreEqual("case 2 or default", func(0));
            Assert.AreEqual("case 2 or default", func(4));
        }
```

May I do rephrase my question: Is that code "ok" for all c# versions, not only for my current one? My current code should be part of code-docu / guide-lines, so may someone with older VS or C# version is picking it up.

Comment: why not just try it out? Write some tests and see what happens.

Comment: checking ECMA 334 archives from 2001 (section 15.7.2), it seems valid there (although it isn't *explicit* - there's just nothing to *disallow* it) - so I guess: always fine

Comment: 1) it's explicitly stated in the docs that it's allowed. 2) testing this on your own would be faster than writing this question: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6rJSOD

Comment: Btw you don't need the parens - `case 2:` is fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ECMA 334 C# specification 1st edition from 2001 has an example of exactly this on p187, section 15.7.2:

```cs
32 switch (i) {
33 default:
34    CaseAny();
35    break;
36 case 1:
37    CaseZeroOrOne();
38    goto default;
39 case 0:
40    CaseZero();
41    goto case 1;
42 }
```

so: it has always been valid

Comment: The link to [ECMA 334 C# specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-334/) and in detail to [v1 from 2001 as PDF](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_1st_edition_december_2001.pdf)